# Function to rename partitions error

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I am trying to rename the partitions of a partition table with the below funtion:

```
create or replace 
function         MYFUNCTION(PSCHEMANAME in varchar2, PTABLENAME in varchar2,PINITNAME in varchar2) 
  return varchar2 
  is 

 DEFAULT_NAME varchar2(10);
 LRETVALUE VARCHAR2(1000):='0';
 EMESG varchar2(1000); 
 ECODE    NUMBER(38);

BEGIN
 FOR X IN (SELECT PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PTABLENAME' AND PARTITION_NAME NOT LIKE 'PINITNAME_%')
 LOOP
   execute immediate 'select to_char('||X.HIGH_VALUE||'-1,''YYYYMMDD'') from dual' into DEFAULT_NAME;
   execute immediate 'alter table'|| PTABLENAME ||' rename partition '||X.PARTITION_NAME||' to PINITNAME_'||DEFAULT_NAME;
   LRETVALUE:= ('0-Successful');
        RETURN lretvalue;
 END LOOP;
  EXCEPTION
       when OTHERS then lretvalue := '1,Problem....'||sqlcode||','||sqlerrm||';
        RETURN lretvalue;
END MYFUNCTION;
```

I am getting an error saying..A call to PL/SQL function completed, but no RETURN statement was executed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the RETURN out of the loop:

```
create or replace 
function         MYFUNCTION(PSCHEMANAME in varchar2, PTABLENAME in varchar2,PINITNAME in varchar2) 
  return varchar2 
  is 

 DEFAULT_NAME varchar2(10);
 LRETVALUE VARCHAR2(256) := '0';
 EMESG varchar2(1000); 
 ECODE    NUMBER(38);

BEGIN
 FOR X IN (SELECT PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_NAME = PTABLENAME AND PARTITION_NAME NOT LIKE 'PINITNAME_%')
 LOOP
   execute immediate 'select to_char('||X.HIGH_VALUE||'-1,''YYYYMMDD'') from dual' into DEFAULT_NAME;
   execute immediate 'alter table '|| PTABLENAME ||' rename partition '||X.PARTITION_NAME||' to PINITNAME_'||DEFAULT_NAME;
 END LOOP;

 LRETVALUE := ('0-Successful');
 RETURN LRETVALUE;

  EXCEPTION
       when OTHERS then RETURN '1,Problem....'||sqlcode||','||sqlerrm;        
END MYFUNCTION;
/
```

Comment: yes, see my edited answer above, but in this case I would return the string directly

Comment: I am trying to execute the function 
select MYFUNCTION('<SCHEMA_NAME>','<TABLE_NAME>','<INITIAL_NAME>') from dual;
I am simply getting the result as '0-Successful'.But it is not actually executing the function.

Comment: FOR X IN ... PTABLENAME was quoted + alter table with missing space, try again